# R Wordcloud taking over 12 hours, can I speed this up

Tags: r, big-o, word-cloud

I have an R tm Corpus at 638MB in 3 parts (source docs). When I tried to get a 100 word word cloud it took12 hours (running still). Is there a way to make this faster?

This is my command, should get 100 words.

```
wordcloud(cleanFullCorpus, max.words = 100, random.order = FALSE, colors=brewer.pal(10,'Spectral'))
```

I was hoping to avoid subsetting the source documents, but can if needed.

Is it possible to extract the top 100 words then build the word cloud?

Any other ideas to make this faster are appreciated.

Gary
PS If it helps my machine had 32 gig of ram, 10 used and an 8 core amd chip running at about 18%

Comment: You'll get better answers if you create a large reproducible sample dataset.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are passing the corpus into `wordcloud`, where you should just be passing a vector of the unique terms and their frequencies.

```
tdm<-TermDocumentMatrix(cleanFullCorpus)
termFreqs<-row_sums(tdm)

wordcloud(names(termFreqs), termFreqs, max.words = 100, random.order = FALSE, colors=brewer.pal(10,'Spectral'))
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. I tried this on a  less powerful computer, the verdict is still out. (Its still running too ...)

Comment: Making a TDM should not be that computationally expensive. If you could provide the code that got you to the `worcloud` command we could provide a lot more help.

Answer (score -1):

wordcloud() probably is NOT optimized to clean up for you.  First get a vector of words and a vector of their associated counts for the ENTIRE CORPUS.  Then pass this vector of length 100 to the wordcloud.